# Does $ 2=5x+x\log x$ have a closed form solution?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I tried to find the solution for the equation:

$$
2=5x+x\log x,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\log x=\frac{2}{x}-5.
$$

It doesn't seem to  admit an exact solution. I only found that the numerical solution is $0.47$. Please help or give me some hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $\dfrac2x=y$, the equation $$2=5x+x\log x$$

turns to (after some rewrite)

$$ye^y=2e^5.$$

This is a Lambert equation, which proves that there is no closed-form solution (except using the ad-hoc function $W$).

Comment: Following your procedure, I have $x=\frac{2}{W(2e^5)}$ which is different from $e^{W(2e^5)-5}$. Both are approximately 0.47. I am confused.

Comment: Since $W$ has a property that $z=W(z)e^{W(z)}$, we have $\frac{2}{W(2e^5)}=e^{W(2e^5)-5}$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Relevant graph]

First of all this equation has two real solutions:

$$ x \approx 146.399 $$
$$ x \approx 0.326899$$

this can be seen on the graph below, or by considering asymptotic behavior of both functions.

Comment: Since Tony already obtained a numerical solution, I think this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I believe this is highly relevant as:
a) previous answer doesn't even mention that there are two solutions
b) the numerical solution OP obtained is not correct even to one significant digit

Comment: I am so sorry! The equation should reduce to $\log x=\frac{2}{x}-5$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It is $$x={{\rm e}^{{\rm W} \left(2\,{{\rm e}^{5}}\right)-5}}$$

Comment: Could you please tell me what $W$ is? Thanks.

Comment: This is the so called LambertW function.